# Are ubuntu optional/switches behave differently with different commands? If no, why is there no cheat sheet listing them all?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line-arguments

There are numerous Ubuntu switches/options, which change the behavior of a ubuntu command. In simplest words, `ls` behaves differently than after we attach the option/switch `-a` ( so that is: `ls -a`) . And if we add the same `-a` to another command, say `apt -a`, would the same option/swich `-a` would try to behave the same way, or it could behave some other way with this command?

I googled very much, but all I got were the numerous websites explaining Ubuntu commands, I couldn't find a single page explaining all the optional switches. 
Let me try in other words, can there be no more than 26 such switches/options-- a to z? All behaving same way with diff commands? Or there can be unlimited such options (though I can't think of them that way). 
Thanks.

Edit: Hope my query is legitimate and within forum rules.

Comment: We can help you understand the optional switches for a command, but if you want a list of all the optional switches for every command that exists, that type of question is extremely broad.  There are entire books written that are hundreds of pages long with what your asking.  Additionally, you can determine the switches for a command, by using the *man* command to display the optional switches for any command.

Comment: `There can be no more than 26 such switches/options-- a to z? Or am I wrong and there are more?` – This many *per command*; plus capital letters; and digits; and long options like `--posix`; and syntax like `count=`. Read manuals.

Comment: This comment is equal to an answer to me. 
I thought there can only be some 26 some switches. 
You said 'this many per command', does it mean that different optional switches behave diff way with the diff commands?

Comment: `optional switches behave diff way with the diff commands?` – The other way around: different commands behave differently. It seems you think options are global. They are not. When you run `ls -a`, the option only affects `ls` and `ls` decides what the option does. And when you run `date -a`, `date` decides (e.g. it may tell you the option is invalid). In general tools are independent from one another in interpreting their options. Options are just strings. It's convention and context that makes them options. E.g. `echo -a` will most likely *print* `-a` because *this tool* works this way.

Comment: Thank you. This ***IS*** the answer to me. If you could write it as an answer, I would mark it as the solution. Thanks.

Comment: My comment may be an answer to your underlying problem, yet the question itself still asks for a guide to all/most options. This is too broad, therefore it was put on hold and nobody can add an answer. Additionally asking for learning material recommendations is off-topic. If you edit the question and change it (e.g. "Are command line options common to many tools? Is there any convention so e.g. `-a` always means 'show all'"?), it may be reopened. Then I will be able to post an answer (but I won't, keep reading). While editing, pay attention not to invalidate the answer you already got. (cont)

Comment: (cont'd) I think the existing answer is good (I upvoted it). If I were you, I would change the question per my example above and explain to the author of the answer I misunderstood the scope of options. I would encourage them to explicitly address this misunderstanding and (after they do) accept the answer. They can use my comments, I don't mind. I'm glad I could help but there's no need for another answer.

Comment: I was not asking about all such commands. I was asking whether there are only 26 such switches/options (ranging from -a to -z) and if there are indeed this many only, then perhaps somebody could guide me to some such cheat sheet. That was when I originally posted the question.

Now I understand that they (might) behave diff with different commands (`-a` may behave differently with `ls`, and in yet another way with `apt`).
So, I've changed/edited the question trying to be as logical and within forum rules as possible for me. Still I'm open to suggestion, how could I improve it further.

Answer (score 3):

There is no consistency among the various commands you'll find on a Linux distribution because they're written by different authors for various unrelated purposes. What might help is looking at the "[manpage](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/)" for a tool you're interested in (though they contain documentation for almost all terminal-based tools available, you read them per-tool). You can find them in your terminal by typing `man [tool]` (e.g. `man ls`), or by googling the tool name along with "man" (e.g. "ls man", [linux.die.net/man](https://linux.die.net/man/) often ranks highly for these searches).

Comment: Ok. But that I was aware of. I was confused among the different things different switches/options (like -a -h -w ) do in Ubuntu's latest version. 
But anyhow, as you told, no separate guides can be found, as they've not been written.

Comment: I'm still unsure as to what you're referring. Are you speaking about switches for `ls` (in which case you want `man ls`, or something else?

Comment: I was asking about different options (aren't they called switches also?) which we put after  a command like 'ls'. Examples of the options/switches I'm talking about are like: -a -h -w -s (and many more like these).

But seeing the responses above (including my question being marked as 'too borad- on hold' shows that my question is not correct or correctly worded.

Or perhaps, if I put '-h' after 'ls' then it may have diff meaning than if i put same '-h' after some other command like 'df'.

Comment: @BathindaHelper you can't just add them as you see fit - each command has it's own options, where the only one common among them might be `--help`.

Comment: Ok, I got it now. That different options/switches behave differently with different commands. It looked strange to me in the beginning, but now, after these answers and many comments, I understand that it is the way it is.